# Link generator can't handle non-ASCII characters

Tags: bug, markdown-rendering

Examples:

[http://ideas.lang-learn.org/Images/yalnızlarım.png](http://ideas.lang-learn.org/Images/yaln%C4%B1zlar%C4%B1m.png)

The first time the link ended with "yaln"  The second time it ended with "Images/"

```
[link](http://ideas.lang-learn.org/Images/yalnızlarım.png)
```

This one, if not escaped by spaces, removes both ı from the link.

Comment: That's technically not a valid URL, though. If it is copied from a URL in a browser address bar, the browser will paste special characters URL encoded

Comment: I guess I’ll have to research that.  Since EVERY browser I’ve tried has accepted Unicode for years, I assumed that standards had escaped the medieval ASCII-only mindset.  And I guess it’s another bug that the dupe-finder didn’t offer me that other question, when both have three title words in common.

Comment: What browsers do internally is, they URL encode anything they get that contains Unicode characters. Conversely, when you copy  from the address bar, you end up with a URLencoded result when you paste it, say, in a text editor. Still, the argument *could* be made that SE should take care of the URL encoding and/or accept URLs with Unicode characters